# SpicIE - OnDocumentComplete not being called

Tags: c#, .net, bho, ieaddon

I downloaded the SimpleLogger sample add-on. When I ran it, I noticed that OnDocumentComplete is not being called. OnBeforeNavigate is being called though. What can be the reason that its not being called. I'm using IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out the answer for this problem. The trouble was being caused due to spicie which I installed from spicie site. I compiled the project again and put the spicie dll in my project folder and it solved the problem.